# Storing unstructured data with ramses to be searched with Ramses-API?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I would like to give my users the possibility to store unstructured data in JSON-Format, alongside the structured data, via an API generated with Ramses.

Since the data is made available via Elasticsearch, I try to achieve that this data is indexed and searchable, too.

I can't find any mentioning in the docs or searching.
Would this be possible and how would one do it?

Cheers /Carsten

Comment: @chris: Can't copy over your answer to a comment. Trying as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Chrisses answer, copied from gitter.im:

You can use the dict field type for "unstructured data", as it takes arbitrary json. If the db engine is postgres, it uses jsonfield under the hood, and if the db engine is mongo, it's converted to a bson document as usual. Either way it should index automatically as expected in ES and will be queryable through the Ramses API.

The following ES queries are supported on documents/fields: nefertari-readthedocs-org/en/stable/making_requests.html#query-syntax-for-elasticsearch

See the docs for field types here, start at the high level (ramses) and it should "just work", but you can see what the code is mapped to at each level below down to the db if desired:

- ramses: ramses-readthedocs-org/en/stable/fields.html
- nefertari (underlying web framework): nefertari-readthedocs-org/en/stable/models.html#wrapper-api
- nefertari-sqla (postgres-specific engine): nefertari-sqla-readthedocs-org/en/stable/fields.html
- nefertari-mongodb (mongo-specific engine): nefertari-mongodb-readthedocs-org/en/stable/fields.html

Let us know how that works out, sounds like it could be a useful thing. So far we've just used that field type to hold data like user settings that the frontend wants to persist but for which the API isn't concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I put an answer here because needed to give a several docs links and this is a new SO account limited to a couple: https://gitter.im/ramses-tech/ramses?at=56bc0c7a4dfe1fa71ffc0b61

Comment: Your account having low rep does not stop you from adding links to your answer.

Comment: well I tried and it said the max was 2 links, but needed to give more